# The Cyclomatic Complexity of this method "setHeader" is 139 which is greater than 10 authorized

Tags: java-8, sonarqube

I have 139 switch cases in setHeader

```
private static void setHeader(String headertableField, String headerValue) {
    switch (headertableField) {
        case AUS:
            headerDTO.setAudval(StringUtils.getTrimValueAfterNullCheck(headerValue));
            break;

        case AXL:
            headerDTO.setAxlfieldl(StringUtils.getTrimValueAfterNullCheck(headerValue));
            break;

        ................
        ..................
        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

It shows sonar issues. Can you please suggest any solution to reduce complexity.

Comment: 139 switches... I just imagined how that looks like :| may be a `Map` instead? `Map<Enum, Consumer<HeaderDTO>>`?

Comment: This large number of cases may be a clue that the 139 behaviours should live somewhere else, outside this class. Using a `Map`, as @Eugene, may resolve the SonarQube issue, but don't take this superficial fix as a license to stop thinking about code improvement.

Comment: @Jubobs what if the OP really has this many possibilities? I don't think that any type of re-factoring would help

Comment: btw you could accept an answer here... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

Eugene's answer is pretty good, but you can go step further and use the same logic inside enum

```
enum HeaderField {
    AUS(HeaderDTO::setAudval),
    AXL(HeaderDTO::setAxlfieldl);

    private BiConsumer<HeaderDTO, String> fieldSetter;

    HeaderField(BiConsumer<HeaderDTO, String> setter) {
        fieldSetter= setter;
    }

    public void setField(HeaderDTO headerDTO, String value) {
        fieldSetter.accept(headerDTO, value);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
HeaderField.AUS.setField(headerDTO, "value");
HeaderField.AXL.setField(headerDTO, "axl");
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of background first:

When you use `case/switch` with `String`, it's not a plain if/else/equals check. Internally (unlike for `int` types for example), first `hashCode` is computed on the String you are switching on and a `lookupswitch` is invoked on that.

If this hashCode value is equal to one of the values present in the case statements (it means that potentially this String is equal to the one you are looking for), do a another `lookupswitch` on a predefined value that depends on where you are "coming from" (previous lookupswitch tells you where to jump).

Anyway, doing String switch is actually a lookupswitch that is `O(1)` (even if doing two of them).

What you can do, is hide away this complexity at the same price of `O(1)` via a `Map`.

```
Map<String, BiConsumer<HeaderDTO, String>> MAP = Map.of(
      "AUS", (x, y) -> x.setAudval(StringUtils.getTrimValueAfterNullCheck(y))
      // all other cases
)
```

and then simply having this map do a :

```
private static void setHeader(String headertableField, String headerValue){
    MAP.get(headertableField).accept(headerDTO, headerValue);
}
```